# Azure Blob storage client library get downloading links

Tags: azure-blob-storage, azure-storage-files, azure-storage-account

This question is regarding which property of the Azure blob storage client library will give me the url of the blob.

I am following the following tutorial to get a list of all blobs in my container. I want to be eventually able to click on a blob and download it.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/quickstart-blobs-javascript-browser#prerequisites

What I don't know is how to get the SAS URL link for the blob from the code below. Like what property of blobItem will give me the URL to download it from.

blobItem. which property???

What property will allow me to get a downloadable link and then I will need to stream it down.

on this line of code

```
fileList.innerHTML += `<option value=${blobItem.value.name}>${blobItem.SOME LINK}</option>`;
```

from the following block

```
const listFiles = async () => {
    fileList.size = 0;
    fileList.innerHTML = "";
    try {
        reportStatus("Retrieving file list...");
        let iter = containerClient.listBlobsFlat();
        let  blobItem = await iter.next();
        while (!blobItem.done) {
            fileList.size += 1;
           // fileList.innerHTML += `<option>${blobItem.value.name}</option>`;
            fileList.innerHTML += `<option value=${blobItem.value.name}>${blobItem.SOME LINK}</option>`;
            blobItem = await iter.next();
        }
        if (fileList.size > 0) {
            reportStatus("Done.");
        } else {
            reportStatus("The container does not contain any files.");
        }
    } catch (error) {
        reportStatus(error.message);
    }
};
```

Answer (score 1):

I think I got the answer in case it will help someone. This line of code will give the url to the blob item inside a container

```
${containerClient.getBlobClient(blobItem.value.name).url}
```

And this is how it can be seen in the document posted above. Replace this line

```
  fileList.innerHTML += `<option>${blobItem.value.name}</option>`;
```

with to be able to see the url

```
fileList.innerHTML += `<option value=${blobItem.value.name}>${containerClient.getBlobClient(blobItem.value.name).url}</option>`;
```

Answer (score 0):

According to the documentation at [Create a service SAS for a blob](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/sas-service-create?tabs=javascript#create-a-service-sas-for-a-blob):

```
function getBlobSasUri(containerClient, blobName, sharedKeyCredential, storedPolicyName) {
    const sasOptions = {
        containerName: containerClient.containerName,
        blobName: blobName
    };

    if (storedPolicyName == null) {
        sasOptions.startsOn = new Date();
        sasOptions.expiresOn = new Date(new Date().valueOf() + 3600 * 1000);
        sasOptions.permissions = BlobSASPermissions.parse("r");
    } else {
        sasOptions.identifier = storedPolicyName;
    }

    const sasToken = generateBlobSASQueryParameters(sasOptions, sharedKeyCredential).toString();
    console.log(`SAS token for blob is: ${sasToken}`);

    return `${containerClient.getBlockBlobClient(blobName).url}?${sasToken}`;
}
```

Comment: Sorry maybe my question isnt clear. I am not asking about how to get the URL from the Portal. This is regarding JS library that should have a property to get the url in the code blobItem. which property???

Comment: Updated answer.

Comment: thanks. The link for Create a service SAS for a blob is not working. Seems like it didnt get pasted propertly. The document that I am following does not have sharedkeyCredentails and storedPolicyName. The function you posted needs that to create the url. I am not sure how this function will work without those two params.

Comment: Seems like this is the link you posted. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/sas-service-create?tabs=javascript

Comment: It was, and I updated the link. So, these links don't get "downloaded", per se, they get *generated*, and you have to have the correct credentials and privileges in order to do that. It seems very likely to me that at some point in this process you're going to need some form of credential like an access key.

Comment: Thanks, what I was hoping to do was if you notice the documentation displays the names of blobs, I was hoping to create a href link in the options html with the direct link to the blob. When the user clicks on that option, that should trigger a download function. If you read the documentation, it starts off with the SASURL to the storage account.  And then creates a containerClient by using getContainerClient object.

Comment: The code begins with placeholder for storage account // Update <placeholder> with your Blob service SAS URL string
const blobSasUrl = "<placeholder>";

Comment: The Blob service SAS URL is built by convention as `blobserviceURL/SAS token`, so something like: `https://yourstorageaccountname.blob.core.windows.net/?sv=alltherestofyourSAStokenhere`

If you go to that page on the storage account and generate a SAS token, it will show you how the SAS URL for blob storage is constructed.

Comment: Where can I get the sharedKeyCredentails from? Because I think for individual files inside the container after the files are listed. The sas token will need to be built on the fly, something similar to what you have in the function.

Comment: I think this is the documentation for the library I am using https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-js/tree/master/sdk/storage/storage-blob

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/@azure/storage-blob/?view=azure-node-latest#generateBlobSASQueryParameters_BlobSASSignatureValues__StorageSharedKeyCredential_ shows a Javascript example of how to get a value into the sharedKeyCredential. You're going to need the Access Key for the storage account. You need to know that this is playing with fire, because you'll need to persist this somewhere, and it's basically the admin password for the storage account.

Comment: @waitingforGucamole, I think I found a way to get the url for the blob to display. Please see my answer. Since the account information and sas token at the storage account level were already provided, getBlobClient function was able to provide info on the file names.